# Laravel 5 Auth::id() returns NULL in UserFactory.php

Tags: authentication, laravel-5, null

i want to store my authenticated user id in one of my tables.In my **UserFactory.php** i write

```
$factory->define(App\Programming::class, function (Faker $faker) {
return [

    'name' => $faker->name,
    'user_id'=>Auth::id(),

];});
```

I am logged in and **use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth** is also included at the top.I get the following error while seeding my data

**Error:**
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null.

Any Solution?Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you log the value of `Auth::id()`? Is `user_id` fillable?

Comment: **Auth::id()** is working fine in my controllers and i check by making the **user_id** fillable . I dont think its not working for fillable field cause without the user_id field i am able to insert other data.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check first before assign to variable

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

if (Auth::check()) {
    $user_id = Auth::id();
}
dd($user_id);
```

Comment: Using **Auth::check()** also returns null. But i'm already logged in! I dont Understand whats going on. @ViperTecPro

Comment: Try running in incognito mode, php artisan config:cache, php artisan config:clear